# tensorboard: error: invalid choice: 'code' (choose from 'serve', 'dev') - while trying to run tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, anaconda, tensorboard

When I try to run tensorboard using the command

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\ANVAY>tensorboard --logdir=D:\Documents\Vs code python\my_log_dir
```

in the anaconda prompt after I have activated tensorflow, I get this error:

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\ANVAY>tensorboard --logdir=D:\Documents\Vs code python\my_log_dir
2020-08-11 23:02:45.376116: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
usage: tensorboard [-h] [--helpfull] [--logdir PATH] [--logdir_spec PATH_SPEC]
                   [--host ADDR] [--bind_all] [--port PORT]
                   [--purge_orphaned_data BOOL] [--db URI] [--db_import]
                   [--inspect] [--version_tb] [--tag TAG] [--event_file PATH]
                   [--path_prefix PATH] [--window_title TEXT]
                   [--max_reload_threads COUNT] [--reload_interval SECONDS]
                   [--reload_task TYPE] [--reload_multifile BOOL]
                   [--reload_multifile_inactive_secs SECONDS]
                   [--generic_data TYPE]
                   [--samples_per_plugin SAMPLES_PER_PLUGIN]
                   [--debugger_data_server_grpc_port PORT]
                   [--debugger_port PORT]
                   {serve,dev} ...
tensorboard: error: invalid choice: 'code' (choose from 'serve', 'dev')
```

**Package versions:**
Tensor Flow Version: 2.1.0
Keras Version: 2.2.4-tf
Python 3.7.7 (default, May  6 2020, 11:45:54) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

I have also tried using the following commands but get the same error

```
tensorboard --logdir D:\Documents\Vs code python\my_log_dir  
python -m tensorboard.main --logdir=D:\Documents\Vs code python\my_log_dir
```

One thing that I noticed while trying to make this work is, in the file `tensorboard-script.py` under the directory `C:\Users\ANVAY\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\Scripts` I get this
[warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jNiy.png) [ `unresolved import 'tensorboard.main'Python(unresolved-import)` ]
and also in the file `main.py` under the directory`C:\Users\ANVAY\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\tensorboard`, I get a similar [warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPG1u.png)

I have no problems with training models and other stuff.

Comment: The problem is probably the spaces in the path, try with --logdir="D:\Documents\Vs code python\my_log_dir"

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thank you. Your solution worked!

Answer (score 6):

From Comments

> The problem is the spaces in the path, try with
> --logdir="D:\Documents\Vs code python\my_log_dir"(paraphrased from Dr. Snoopy)

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when I entered the argument as `--log-dir` instead of `--logdir`.

Comment: same here I typed `logdir` instead of `--logdir` but the error message is a bit strange

Answer (score 0):

For me is running but passing the tensorflow command as bash argument.

I report here the Kubernetes Pod spec that can be used to extract the command:

```yaml
  containers:
  - args:
    # - '--host 0.0.0.0'
    # - '--logdir=/tensorboard_logs/'
    - '-c'
    - '/usr/local/bin/tensorboard --host 0.0.0.0 --logdir=/tensorboard_logs/'
    command:
    # - /usr/local/bin/tensorboard
    - bash
```

The commented lines are the original ones not working.

Answer (score 0):

%tensorboard --logdir="my_log_dir"  --port=8892
Try this in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

Just make the path to the log directory a variable. then put in the the cmd like this.

```
    training_log_path = 'Training\Logs\PPO_1' 
    # or whatever your path is

    tensorboard --logdir=training_log_path
```

or you can just cd straight to your log directory and then put

```
    tensorboard --logdir=.
```

I don't fully understand how all this works but this worked for me and so hopefully for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

adding double quotes and giving the relative address worked for me